# Python - Sum of Excel cell range

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am completely new to python
I have an excel sheet as below:

```
        Column A  Column B   Column C         Column D  
Row 1   Mathew    abc       89499052          17895077  
Row 2   Job       def       89499158          17920464  
Row 3   Robin     ehj       89499254          17901346  
Row 4                      Sumof(C1+c2+c3)   Sumof(D1+D2+D3)  
Row 5                      Result of D4/C4
```

I need a code snippet for below:
1. Open the excel sheet in certain path(E:/Excelfiles/abc.csv)
2. Find the required values C4 and D4.
3. Find value of C5.
Can someone please help me out?

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to try first and ask about the issues here. Good luck.

Comment: First you need to learn some basic programming in python.  There are plenty of tutorials online - I can recommend codeacademy for example.  After you learn the basics, have a look at the 'pandas' package for python - it is designed to do what you want and it is very simple to use.  There are plenty of tutorials for pandas as well.

Answer (score -1):

Sure, you should use Pandas.

```
import pandas as pa

df = pa.read_csv('E:/Excelfiles/abc.csv')
cSum = df['Column C'].sum()
dSum = df['Column D'].sum()
d4 = df['Column D'].iloc[3]
c4 = df['Column C'].iloc[3]
```

I let you find the code left. Please check the [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) function as it may need the encoding parameter depending on your csv file.
You will need to learn Pandas [Doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable)  [Tutorial](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/tutorials.html)  [Article](http://www.data-analysis-in-python.org)  [Book](http://wesmckinney.com/pages/book.html) [R in Python](https://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x) [CookBook](https://github.com/jvns/pandas-cookbook)